# What is a splunk query to get top elements from a list of strings?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
index=foo stringIdList=["id1","id2","id2","id3","id3","id3"]
```

For the above log format, I wish to get a table with the elements in the stringIdList, and their their count. What should the Splunk query be for the same?

I have tried `index=foo | top "navItemIdList"` command, but it's not working as expected. I wish to get the count of each element in the list, as a table.

Answer (score 0):

While "the above log format" looks more like a Splunk query than a log entry, this query may fulfill the request.

````
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="index=foo stringIdList=[\"id1\",\"id2\",\"id2\",\"id3\",\"id3\",\"id3\"]" 
``` Above creates test data.  Delete IRL```
``` Get the list of elements from the raw event ```
| extract pairdelim=" " kvdelim="=" 
``` Remove the enclosing brackets ```
| eval stringIdList=trim(stringIdList,"[]") 
``` Break the list at each comma ```
| eval stringIdList=split(stringIdList,",") 
``` Put each element into its own event ```
| mvexpand stringIdList 
``` Count events and group them by element ```
| stats count by stringIdList
````

Note that the `top` command returns the 10 most common values of the specified field.  In the example, the 'navItemIdList' field doesn't exist so no results can be returned.